# RibbonToggleButton - icon is corrupted

Tags: icons, ribbon, corrupt

I have a ribbon-base app and on it's toggle buttons I'm placing PNG icons - 32x32, 32 bits. But when I'm launching the app the image on the ribbon button looks corrupted. Just to checkk I've create a simple button control with the same image on it - and it looks ok. see the screenshot here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2Zdf.jpg
I've tried to add RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" and RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" to my app window tag - no luck.
Can someone explain whyRibbonToggleButton corrupts the images on it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the image with a program that supports setting the DPI in the metadata, for example [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/). I had a similar problem and changing the images DPI to match the screen fixed it for me.

1. Open the image in IrfanVIew and press shift+i to open the image information dialog
   [image: Open menu item]
2. Change the DPI to match your screen
   [image: Change DPI]
3. Save the image

I have not tested this on a screen that is set to a different DPI, so I have no idea if this will look even more horribly wrong then.

Comment: Hi Tinsa, in general I have several variations of my icons with different DPI - so ys, I found icons with DPIs I need. But here I've faced another problem: how to configure ribbon buttons, togglebuttons etc to have different icons for different DPIs. I fond this article from MS - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316921(v=vs.85).aspx - but in my code I cannot specify Command.LargeImages inside thes tags         <ribbon:RibbonMenuItem.Command></ribbon:RibbonMenuItem.Command>

Comment: Hello, does anyone tried to do the stuff discribed in this MSDN article for ribbon elements?